# changing values of a column in R while drawing reference from another column

Tags: r, dataset

I have a dataset as follows:-

```
RATE    PriceDifference
84        0 
84        0
85        0
85        0
85        0
84        0
83.1      0
```

I want to replace all the values of 2nd column with the difference between this row's `RATE` and the previous row's `RATE`.

An example: The second row should have the value (84 - 84 =) 0 in `PriceDifference`. Similarly, the last row should have a value of -0.9 because 83.1 - 84 = 0.9

Comment: Use `diff`: `c(0,diff(df$RATE))`

Comment: Thanks a ton.. solved my problem